# C# Import CSV in multiple tables using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I cannot make it work to import the data from a `.CSV` file into multiple SQL Server tables while using `SqlBulkCopy`.

It was working to import in a single table.

I am trying with `SqlBulkCopy` because in most of the topics I read it says it's the fastest solution and I need to import every day between 1-2 million lines into 8 tables.

Thank you in advance for any recommendation.

```
namespace SQLBulkDT2012
{
    public class CsvBulkCopyDataIntoSqlServer
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoadCsvDataIntoSqlServer();
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static string GetPath()
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "test.csv");
            return (filePath);
        }

        static void LoadCsvDataIntoSqlServer()
        {
            // This should be the full path
            string filePath = GetPath();
            bool IsSuccessSave = false;

            SqlTransaction _transaction = null;

            using (var textFieldParser = new TextFieldParser(filePath))
            {
                textFieldParser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                textFieldParser.Delimiters = new[] { "," };
                textFieldParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

                var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLBulkDT2012.Properties.Settings.`CMSConnectionString`"].ConnectionString;

                var dataTable = new DataTable("Temp_Table");
                // Add the columns in the temp table
                // 001
                dataTable.Columns.Add("COLUMN_001");
                // 002
                dataTable.Columns.Add("COLUMN_002");
                // 003
                dataTable.Columns.Add("COLUMN_003");
                // 004
                dataTable.Columns.Add("COLUMN_004");
                using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    using (_transaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        // Truncate the live table
                        // Create the bulk copy object
                        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy001 = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, _transaction))
                        {
                            sqlBulkCopy001.BatchSize = 99999;
                            sqlBulkCopy001.DestinationTableName = "SY001_tst";
                            // Setup the column mappings, anything ommitted is skipped
                            // 001
                            sqlBulkCopy001.ColumnMappings.Add("COLUMN_001", "COLUMN_001");
                            // 002
                            sqlBulkCopy001.ColumnMappings.Add("COLUMN_002", "COLUMN_002");
                            sqlBulkCopy001.WriteToServer(Table001);
                        }
                        // Create the bulk copy object
                        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy002 = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, _transaction))
                        {
                            sqlBulkCopy002.BatchSize = 99999;
                            sqlBulkCopy002.DestinationTableName = "SY002_tst";
                            // Setup the column mappings, anything ommitted is skipped
                            // 001
                            sqlBulkCopy002.ColumnMappings.Add("COLUMN_003", "COLUMN_003");
                            // 002
                            sqlBulkCopy002.ColumnMappings.Add("COLUMN_004", "COLUMN_004");
                            sqlBulkCopy002.WriteToServer(Table002);
                        }

                        _transaction.Commit();
                        IsSuccessSave = true;
                    }
                    sqlConnection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `SqlBulkCopy` is extremely fast **because** it only loads directly into one table, and doesn't support any splitting up of data, validation or transformation of data while loading. So you should just import those rows into a **staging table** (directly, using `SqlBulkCopy`), and only **once loaded** distribute them to the 8 target tables in SQL Server

Comment: Use SQLCMD.EXE is faster.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017